# WP_Error could not be converted to string

Tags: wp-error

I try to add an existing user to a blog with the function `add_user_to_blog($blog_id, $user_id, $role)`. The code I use gives me:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted
>   to string in C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\ms-functions.php on
>   line 206.

What do I need to do to make this work?

This is my code:

```
$domain = "";
$path = "localhost/wordpress/wp_4";
$title = "WP_4";
$user_id = 1;
$network_id = get_main_network_id();
$role = 'editor';
$new_blog_id = wpmu_create_blog($domain, $path, $title, $user_id, $network_id);
add_user_to_blog($new_blog_id, $network_id, $role);
```

Comment: Please check your passed arguments. You're passing the `network_id` instead of the `user_id` as the second parameter. Also you should check the value of `$new_blog_id` to ensure you're getting an actual value there.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your code.

First of all, let's see at `wpmu_create_blog` function:

```
wpmu_create_blog(
    string $domain,
    string $path,
    string $title,
    int $user_id,
    array $meta = array(),
    int $network_id = 1
)
```

So you use it incorrectly. It's 5th argument is `$meta` and you put `$network_id` in there...

Another problem is that this function can return `int` (the ID of new site) or WP_Error if some error occured.

You ignore that and assume it always ends with success. And that is causing your error - function returns `WP_Error` and you treat it as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your function result with [`is_wp_error()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_wp_error)

```
<?php
$domain = "";
$path = "localhost/wordpress/wp_4";
$title = "WP_4";
$user_id = 1;
$network_id = get_main_network_id();
$role = 'editor';
$new_blog_id = wpmu_create_blog($domain, $path, $title, $user_id, $network_id);

if(is_wp_error($new_blog_id)) {
    echo $new_blog_id->get_error_message();
    return;
}

$new_user = add_user_to_blog($new_blog_id, $network_id, $role);

if(is_wp_error($new_user)) {
    echo $new_user->get_error_message();
    return;
}
```